# How to write such a table?

Tags: tables

I want to write such a table,
[image]

but I find that the columns are not strictly centered.

How to modify the code to make it correct?

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \toprule
        & Beijing & Shenzhen\\
        & \begin{tabular}{cc}\midrule Price (\$)&Size\end{tabular}
        & \begin{tabular}{cc}\midrule Price (\$)&Size\end{tabular}\\
    \midrule
    House1 & \begin{tabular}{cc}94.80&  94.8000\end{tabular} &  \begin{tabular}{cc}94.80&  94.80\end{tabular}    \\
    House2 & \begin{tabular}{cc}94.80&  94.80\end{tabular} &  \begin{tabular}{cc}94.80&  94.80\end{tabular}    \\
    House3 & \begin{tabular}{cc}94.80&  94.80\end{tabular}&  \begin{tabular}{cc}94.80&  94.80\end{tabular}  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
\end{table}%
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Comment: Why do you have extra tabulars in the middle of your table?

Comment: Do you really need  $4$ decimal digits in the third column thi=rd row?

Comment: And 94.8000 is centered over 94.80.  Do you want it centered like that, or do you want the decimal points to line up?

Comment: @NBur Sorrt for that, and the problem will be happen again next time.   Indeed there is not need to do so, but that is the only way I knew to write such a table. Now I know the right way, as posted by Mico. Thank all of you for kindly help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that by "strictly centered", you mean "centered on the decimal markers". If this interpretation is correct, the following solution may be of interest to you. Compared to the code you posted, it uses a single 5-column `tabular` environment and omits all interior `tabular` environments. It also (a) employs the `S` column type to perform alignment on the decimal markers and (b) provides two `\cmidrule` directives to provide the lines that are shown in the screenshot you posted.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for 'S' column type
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \sisetup{table-format=2.2} % set the default layout
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{} l S S[table-format=2.4] S S @{}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Beijing} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Shenzhen}\\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
    & {Price (\$)} & {Size} & {Price (\$)} & {Size}\\
    \midrule
    House1 & 94.80 & 94.8000 & 94.80 &  94.80   \\
    House2 & 94.80 & 94.80   & 94.80 &  94.80   \\
    House3 & 94.80 & 94.80   & 94.80 &  94.80   \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your table is the exactly what I need, it help a lot

Comment: @陈绍伍 - You're most welcome!